# M-x cider-jack-in keeps starting server forever, but not really starting. How to integrate Emacs development to this Clojure project?

Tags: clojure, ide, cider, nrepl

I am new to Clojure and I am using one of Eirc Normad's course to learn.

After following the instructions, I do a git clone of:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/lispcast/introduction-to-clojure.git
```

Until this point, Eric does not emphasize Emacs' use. But, I would like to use Emacs, since I am used to it.

In Emacs, after opening the file `project.clj`, I executed `cider-jack-in`. A message is echoed by the mini-buffer about the nREPL indicating that the server has been started:

[image]

The situation stays like this for a long time without anything changing.

I must say that I have successfully used CIDER and Emacs in other Clojure projects. Especially, if I start some Clojure project from scratch, e.g. after a `$ lein new my-new-project` .

In addition, although CIDER does not work after the git clone suggested by Eric's material, things do work as expected after openning `eshell` and executing `$ lein repl`, see below:

```shell
Welcome to the Emacs shell

 ~/projects/introduction-to-clojure   master $ lein repl
Welcome to the bakery!

Available commands are: 
grab           Pick something up.
squeeze        Squeeze whatever you are holding.
release        Release whatever you are holding.
scoop          If you are holding the cup, fill it with an ingredient.
add-to-bowl        Add the ingredient you are holding to the mixing bowl.
mix            Mix the ingredients in the bowl.
pour-into-pan      Pour the contents of the bowl into the pan.
bake-pan       Put the pan in the oven for a certain number of minutes.
cool-pan       After baking, put the pan on the cooling racks to cool.
           Returns the id of the cooling rack.
status         Print out the status of the bakery.
start-over     If you get lost, this command will reset the bakery.
go-to          Go to the given location.
           Possible locations are :prep-area, :fridge, and :pantry.
load-up        Load an ingredient from storage to take to the prep area.
unload         Unload an ingredient in the prep area.
get-morning-orders Get a new list of baking orders.
delivery       Notify the delivery bot that something is ready to deliver.

bakery-help      Print out this message.
[Rebel readline] Type :repl/help for online help info
introduction-to-clojure.core=>
```

I am clueless about why it does not work in this particular case.

The buffer *Messages* indicates:

```lisp
[nREPL] Starting server via /run/current-system/sw/bin/lein update-in :dependencies conj \[nrepl/nrepl\ \"0.9.0\"\] -- update-in :plugins conj \[cider/cider-nrepl\ \"0.28.5\"\] -- repl :headless :host localhost
Quit [2 times]
```

Moreover, things get even weirder when inspecting the `*nrepl server*. Things seem to have worked! The REPL seems to be working. There is even a starting message from the project being printed:

```lisp
Welcome to the bakery!

Available commands are: 
grab           Pick something up.
squeeze        Squeeze whatever you are holding.
release        Release whatever you are holding.
scoop          If you are holding the cup, fill it with an ingredient.
add-to-bowl        Add the ingredient you are holding to the mixing bowl.
mix            Mix the ingredients in the bowl.
pour-into-pan      Pour the contents of the bowl into the pan.
bake-pan       Put the pan in the oven for a certain number of minutes.
cool-pan       After baking, put the pan on the cooling racks to cool.
           Returns the id of the cooling rack.
status         Print out the status of the bakery.
start-over     If you get lost, this command will reset the bakery.
go-to          Go to the given location.
           Possible locations are :prep-area, :fridge, and :pantry.
load-up        Load an ingredient from storage to take to the prep area.
unload         Unload an ingredient in the prep area.
get-morning-orders Get a new list of baking orders.
delivery       Notify the delivery bot that something is ready to deliver.

bakery-help      Print out this message.
[Rebel readline] Type :repl/help for online help info

introduction-to-clojure.core=>
```

The REPL is also adjusted to the namespace. However, it **does not** eval the expressions that I insert:

```lisp
introduction-to-clojure.core=> (+ 1 2)


;; does not return any output
```

In case this is relevant, I am using NixOS as OS. This is my NixOS' [config file](https://github.com/pdelfino/my-nixos-config). In addition, this is my Emacs [config file](https://github.com/pdelfino/dotfiles/blob/main/.emacs.d/init.el).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project was set up by the author to be the best for as many people as possible, so Eric Normand included a [clojure library](https://github.com/bhauman/rebel-readline) called **Rebel Readline**. This library addition is the root of the problem.

It is possible to disable it by commenting out the `:aliases` line in the `project.clj`, [here](https://github.com/lispcast/introduction-to-clojure/blob/0ecffb12417d78a5ee2ee1eb02d0e6e453a2083b/project.clj#L11). After this change, it will start a more normal REPL that is compatible with CIDER (Emacs).

The content of this answer was kindly provided by Eric via private email. Errors and omissions are my responsibility.